# Error initializing Fabric CA server, go-sqlite3 requires cgo to work

Tags: vagrant, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have recently update Hyperledger Fabric and associated CA and when initializing I receive the following error:

```
2021/07/02 08:03:55 [DEBUG] Initializing DB
2021/07/02 08:03:55 [DEBUG] Initializing 'sqlite3' database at '/vagrant/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db'
2021/07/02 08:03:55 [DEBUG] Using sqlite database, connect to database in home (/vagrant/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db) directory
2021/07/02 08:03:55 [DEBUG] Creating SQLite database (/vagrant/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db) if it does not exist...
2021/07/02 08:03:55 [ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Failed to open sqlite3 DB: Binary was compiled with 'CGO_ENABLED=0', go-sqlite3 requires cgo to work. This is a stub
```

I have tried to issue the following:

```
export CGO_ENABLED=1
go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/...
```

I have also downloaded the binaries from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/releases, but that gives the same error.

I am using vagrant boxes with virtualbox, the initialization was working previously.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it, I needed to issue the command:

```
export CGO_ENABLED=1
go install github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/fabric-ca-server@latest
```

then copy the fabric-ca-server that was build in the correct directory

Answer (score 0):

FYI _ I encountered this myself in testing, and have raised an issue about it https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/issues/242

Thinking that this really is an error.

Comment: Calanais is correct, I've commented on the issue he noted, in 2020 I introduced an update to Fabric-CA which had a hidden dependency change that introduced CGO code in the SQLite client to make the binary cross-compilable. Unfortunately it had unintended consequences and it was hidden in that we didn't release Fabric again for over a year. I've noted how we can fix this (build the binaries on a native platform) and will attempt to get a fix in shortly.